# A shorter way to write the following function in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this function -

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
 var weeklyvalues=GetWeeklyValues();//gets list of weekly values.
 if (weeklyvalues.Count == 0)
                return 0;
            return (weeklyvalues.Sum() / weeklyvalues.Count);
}
```

Is there a shorter way to write this using `?:` or maybe something else ?

Comment: why do you want to write it shorter? I thought it will be a very loooooooong function.

Comment: just like that i am in process of rewriting some code..so i thought looking at this there might be a better way to write it..and might learn some new ways..Thanks to everyone for their answers !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public double GetAvgResult()
{
    // Assumes GetWeeklyValues() never returns null.
    return GetWeeklyValues().DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
}
```

Do note that this returns a `double` , which I assume is what you *really* want (the average of a bunch of integers is logically not an integer). You can cast it to `int` if necessary, or if you want to stick with integer math all the way:

```
var seq = GetWeeklyValues().DefaultIfEmpty();
return seq.Sum() / seq.Count();
```

Comment: This wins the succinctness award.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
    var weeklyvalues = GetWeeklyValues();
    return (weeklyvalues.Count != 0) ? (weeklyvalues.Sum() / weeklyvalues.Count) : 0;
}
```

or:

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
    return GetWeeklyValues().DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
    var weeklyvalues = GetWeeklyValues(); //gets list of weekly values.
    return weeklyvalues.Count == 0 ? 0 : weeklyvalues.Sum() / weeklyvalues.Count;
}
```

That's as short as I'd attempt to make it. Is there a specific reason (other than code golf) you're trying for a low character count?

Answer (score 1):

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
 var weeklyvalues = GetWeeklyValues();//gets list of weekly values.
 return (weeklyvalues.Count == 0) ? 0 : (weeklyvalues.Sum() / weeklyvalues.Count );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int GetAvgResult()
{
    var weeklyvalues=GetWeeklyValues();//gets list of weekly values.
    return weeklyvalues.Count == 0
        ? 0 
        : (weeklyvalues.Sum() / weeklyvalues.Count);
}
```